# back to referer button wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a wordpress site, which will be used by our partners' e-shops for providing more info to their customers. So, when a customer is on their website and would like more info about a product, after clicking the "More" button, he will be redirected to my website where all information will be available. Then, by hiting a "Buy Now" button, I would like him to be redirected to the referring page, meaning the certain partner's webpage. Is this possible?

Also, if the customer navigates in my website and finds something else to buy, is it possible for him to hit the "Buy now" button and be redirected to the specific product page of the refering partner?

In brief, is it possible to send all "Buy" requests bach to the refering website and in particular to the relevant product page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, What you want is possible.

Add a query variable with current page in "More" button

Example: http://yourdomain.com/product-details/?refer=http://productpage.com/prouct-url

When it go to your information site you must save this "refer" url form $_GET['refer'] variable and set this to "Buy Now" button.

May be it will work for you.